# Why subqueries cannot be used in the SQL override for uncached lookup transformations in PowerCenter?

Tags: subquery, transformation, lookup, informatica, informatica-powercenter

As the question being asked in title:

Why subqueries cannot be used in the SQL override for uncached lookup transformations in PowerCenter?

Is that because subqueries are not allowed in the lookup transformation, or is that because it is being set as "uncached"? and Why?

Answer (score 0):

I guess they can - unless there's something I'm missing. Here's a snapshot of a successfully completed session that is using Non-cached lookup with a subquery, as you can see in the log. Furthermore, I also made sure some data went through indeed, as you can see in the Performance section.

[image]